# From vector to matrix reshape every ith rows for each column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, resize, reshape

I have this vector:

```
arr = [1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3]
```

And would like to turn it into a 4x3 matrix looking like this:

```
mat = [1 1 1;...
2 2 2;...
3 3 3;...
1 1 1;...
2 2 2;...
3 3 3;...
1 1 1;...
2 2 2;...
3 3 3;...
1 1 1;...
2 2 2;...
3 3 3]
```

So far I achieved this by doing:

```
a1 = arr(1:3:end);
a2 = arr(2:3:end);
a3 = arr(3:3:end);
mat = [a1 a2 a3];
```

Is there a more convenient way with for instance the `reshape` function?

Answer (score 2):

`reshape` does not change the number of the elements in a matrix. It *reshapes* the matrix by rearranging the *existing* elements.

In your case, you can use `repmat`, which copies a matrix or vector one or multiple times:

```
mat = repmat(arr,1,3);
```

You can read more about `repmat` [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html?s_tid=doc_ta).

---

Also, your solution does not give the matrix you showed in the code block. To get the result given by your solution, you can use `reshape` as such:

```
mat = reshape(arr,3,4)'
```

Comment: Note that `'` also applies a complex conjugate. To just transpose use `.'`